# Pronombres personales y su función sintáctica

Tags: pronombres, sintaxis

Estoy leyendo La Casa de Bernarda Alba de Federico García Lorca. Encontré una frase que no era capaz de analizar:

> Es capaz de sentarse encima de tu corazón y ver cómo te mueres durante un año sin que **se le cierre esa sonrisa fría** que lleva en su maldita cara.

En la oración subordinada (en negrita) ¿Cuáles son las funciones sintácticas? ¿Es sujeto "esa sonrisa fría"? ¿es complemento indirecto el "le"? ¿Está construido en la misma forma que los verbos que se usan con complemento indirecto (gustar, encantar, interesar etc.)? ¿Qué función tiene el "se"?

¿Puede ser que el "se" es complemento indirecto, y el "le" complemento directo como en "se le da" (He gives him to her)? Parece muy extraño.

Verdad es que no entiendo. Cualquier ayuda es muy apreciada.

Comment: Hint: In  a sentence like "Se me acaba la vida", the subject is "la vida".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es correcto que el sujeto de la oración subordinada es «esa sonrisa fría».  El pronombre «se» tiene una función reflexiva (aunque podría pensarse también como una voz media<sup>1.</sup>):

> Esa sonrisa fría se cierra.

En este caso la sonrisa también es el objeto directo (qué es lo que es cerrado) y el «le» es por lo tanto el complemento indirecto (a quién o para quien la sonrisa se cierra):

> Esa sonrisa fría se le cierra (a él *o* a ella).

Nótese que la oración subordinada completa incluye y contiene a otra oración subordinada.  El sujeto (y complemento directo) completo es: «esa sonrisa fría que lleva en su maldita cara.»

<sup>1. voz media: es una construcción en la cual el paciente de un verbo transitivo como «cerrar» se convierte en el sujeto.  En una oración semánticamente reflexiva «la sonrisa se cierra» la sonrisa sería tanto el agente (quien cierra) como el paciente (quien es cerrado).  En este caso la sonrisa es el paciente pero no hay cabida para un agente explícito o tácito.  Una voz media en contraste con la voz activa: «El sujeto cierra su sonrisa» o la voz pasiva: «La sonrisa es cerrada (por su sujeto)».</sup>

Comment: Eso tiene sentido. Pero ¿Cómo llegar a la conclusión de que no cabe agente?

Comment: El agente es la respuesta a la pregunta _«¿Quién o qué le cierra esa sonrisa fría que lleva en su maldita cara?»_, en este caso visto desde el punto de vista gramatical y no desde el punto de vista biológico.  Es decir: de acuerdo a como está construida la frase ¿quién o qué es el agente?  El agente podría ser explícito: _«Ella cerró su sonrisa»_, tácito: _«Cerró su sonrisa»_ o _«Esa sonrisa fue cerrada»_.  La construcción con pronombre reflexivo puede ser reflexiva (la sonrisa se cerró a si misma), impersonal (sin agente ni sujeto) o media (sin agente, objeto como sujeto).